# How can I link objects with applied rotations?

Tags: linked-data

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

All of these screws have a rotation of (0,0,0). Which means their rotation has already been applied. If I select them all and link them, they will all share the rotation of the active screw. Is there any way to preserve their current rotation during the 'link' operation?

I am guessing that you would need to use geometry nodes to *analyze* the current geometry. Each screw would have the same geonodes modifier, and would rotate about x,y,z until it *minimized* some property, like inertia. I know this is abstract thinking but maybe it will help somebody think of something clever.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UaoK.jpg

Comment: I don't understand, if all the screws have a rotation of 0, if you join them nothing should change since all of them have the same rotation?

Comment: He wrote "link" not "join" which is a different operation.

Comment: there's no way, they will all have the same orientation, or you need to save each orientation with as many custom orientations as you have objects

Comment: Imagine an assembly with thousands of screws. There's no way to replace each screw with an instance?

Comment: as the objects rotated from their origins?

Comment: you can replace them with a linked mesh but as they all have a 0:0:0 rotation I don't see (at least with the basic tools) how you can keep the visual orientations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming all objects have initially been rotated from their origin and there is no other operation on them (no translation for instance).

We need to find two vertices that are not aligned with the mesh origin.

If these two exist, we can calculate two rotations in order to find the wanted result.

Below, green/blue is the object and yellow/red is the reference.

First rotation is the one that goes from one of the vectors to the other:

[image]

Once this rotation applied, to the green and blue, we have green over yellow and we have blue rotated:

[image]

Now we want this rotation, with the green/yellow as axis:

[image]

The following code does it. Select all the objects you want to "unrotate" with the reference one as active object and run the code.

```
import bpy
from math import degrees
from mathutils import Matrix

# loop over the vertices in order to find
# 2 of them that are not aligned with the 
# origin of the mesh
def pick_points(verts, epsilon = 0.01):
    for i1 in range(len(verts)):
        v1 = verts[i1].co.normalized()
        for i2 in range(i1 + 1, len(verts)):
            v2 = verts[i2].co.normalized()
            if v1.cross(v2).length > epsilon:
                return i1, i2, v1, v2
    return None, None, None, None

# Take the reference object, the active one
reference = bpy.context.active_object
# Find reference vertices for it
i1, i2, v1, v2 = pick_points(reference.data.vertices)

if i1 is None:
    print("All vertices are aligned")
else:
    # The vector formed by the projection of v2 on v1 to v2
    pv2 = v2 - v2.project(v1)

    # Loop over the selected object
    for o in [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o != reference]:
        # Get the two vertices at same indices
        ov1 = o.data.vertices[i1].co.normalized()
        ov2 = o.data.vertices[i2].co.normalized()

        # Get the rotation separating ov1 and the reference v1
        q1 = ov1.rotation_difference(v1)
        # Rotate ov2 with this rotation
        ov2 = q1 @ ov2
        # Get the vector formed by the projection of ov2 on v1 to ov2
        pov2 = ov2 - ov2.project(v1)
        # Get the rotation separating these to "p" vectors
        q2 = pov2.rotation_difference(pv2)

        # Combine the rotations = how to go from o to the reference
        q = q2 @ q1

        # Extract current world matrix components of o
        t, _, s = o.matrix_world.decompose()

        # Assign it the same component, but replacing the rotation part
        # which is calculated above inverted
        o.matrix_world = Matrix.LocRotScale(t, q.inverted(), s)

    # Link objects to the ref/active one
    bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='OBDATA')
```

---

Here is your file (I've used V4.0 here), with a copy of the screws and the script applied.

All works as expected:

Select them all with the original screw as active.

Run the script.

And the screws are instances with the wanted rotations.

[image]

Comment: WOW. Ok I will try this now

Comment: This is a really great answer, but I'm still back where I started. I have an assembly of the same screw in all sorts of orientations, but they are not instances - so they take a lot of unneeded memory. I need them to maintain their rotation after linking them.

Comment: Well, JB, this is what the script is supposed to do. It does not work for your case?

Comment: I could achieve the same results as this script by simply linking them. The problem with this script, and linking, is that all the screws change their rotation to match the active, I need them to stay the way they are, yet become instances.

Comment: I've tested it and the script works for me here. Could you share a sample file with the screws, please?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w2X7QqO6rB5U-nkVI1vRBuIXunYLWeVp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your file added in the answer.

Comment: But did you see that it does not maintain the current orientation of each screw after executing the python script?

Comment: No, I do not see that. On left originals, on right script applied (front and top views): https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9sJE.png

Comment: WOW! It seems to have worked!!! I'm sorry if I did something wrong but this is SUPERB! This is the answer. Thank you so so so much

Comment: Happy that finally works for you... at last ;)

Comment: It does not seem to work all of the time for every assembly, but I cannot figure why

Comment: ok... please share again some sample

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14WdzO6a3mVPEcjx-2t81FF-nklXeozf_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok, this is right this time. That's a bug. I'll have a look at it when possible.

Comment: In fact, they have the same shape but don't have the same vertex indices... so they are not exact copies, it seems.

Comment: Look at these indices: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJAAZ.png ... If this is to "unrotate" different meshes (event if they look the exact same), this is another story...

Comment: I did not realize some of these were slightly different meshes. you are right, this is a whole different case. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to do that. If the rotation is applied, you loose it so there is nowhere to get that back from.

You could attempt to get that information from the geometry in a Python script. For example you could compare the average of normals of all faces to the initial rotation of the first object and then figure out what the rotation should be based on that. Since the geometry is not completely symmetrical, I suspect that vector from averaging all face normals would be somehow relative to the orientation of the geometry and the same in all of them assuming the geometries are exact copies. Sounds like a lot of work for 5 screws. If you had hundreds of them, maybe that would pay off.

Comment: FYI, my answer here. This is possible... considering there is only a rotation around the origin... If I was wrong for some cases, please tell me.